# Divide full list to k fold training and testing set?

Tags: perl

I currently have a perl script which takes a full file list, and evenly divides the list into a train and test set. I now wants to do k-fold cross validation for which i need to perl script to be adjusted to do so.

But I seem to have a hard time coming up with an simple solution, given the current implementation.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$full_list = $ARGV[0];
$test_list = $ARGV[1];
$train_list = $ARGV[2];

open FL, $full_list;
$nol = 0;
while ($l = <FL>)
{
    $nol++;
}
close FL;

$i = 0;
open FL, $full_list;
open TESTLIST, ">$test_list";
open TRAINLIST, ">$train_list";
while ($l = <FL>)
{
    chomp($l);
    $i++;
    if ($i <= $nol/2 )
    {
        print TRAINLIST "$l\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print TESTLIST "$l\n";
    }
}
```

My simple attempt of making it possible to create a k folds is by introducing two new input parameters being `part` as `argv[4]` and `k` `argv[3]`.  So a part of `$nol` is used to generate the test set and the rest will be the train set.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$full_list = $ARGV[0];
$test_list = $ARGV[1];
$train_list = $ARGV[2];
$k = $ARGV[3]
$part_index_end = $ARGV[4]
$part_index_start = $ARGV[4]-1


print "Hi";

open FL, $full_list;
$nol = 0;
while ($l = <FL>)
{
    $nol++;
}
close FL;

$i = 0;
open FL, $full_list;
open TESTLIST, ">$test_list";
open TRAINLIST, ">$train_list";
while ($l = <FL>)
{
    chomp($l);
    $i++;
    if ($i <= ($nol/$k)*$part_index_end $$ $i => ($nol/$k)*$part_index_end )
    {
        print TESTLIST "$l\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print TRAINLIST "$l\n";
    }
}
```

This though requires an other script that call this script with increasing part parameter, such that they also are placed correctly, and don't overwrite the same file.

The outcome of the script should be 3 sets of train/test list.

Comment: Okay, you've shown your starting point, but you haven't shown what you've tried to convert it. Do you understand what K-fold cross-validation is? Do you know what you want your program to produce?

Comment: I added my attempt, and how i want it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution i ended up using was:

```
/* cook your code below */
k=5
for (( j=1; j<k; j++ ))
do
    for (( i=1; i<k; i++ ))
    do

        if [ $i == $j ] && [ $j == $((k-1)) ]
        then
            s+="1"
            #echo "1"
        elif [ $i == $j ] 
        then 
            s+="1_"
            #echo "1"
        elif [ $i == $((k-1)) ]
        then 
            s+="0"
            #echo "0"
        else
            s+="0_"
            #echo "0_"
        fi  
    done
    echo $s
    s=""
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want lines 1, n+1, 2n+1, ... in one file; lines 2, n+2, 2n+2, ... in another; etc.

```
my @out_fhs;
for my $i (1..$n) {
   my $out_qfn = sprintf("file%03d", $i);
   open(my $out_fh, '>', $out_qfn)
      or die("Can't create \"$out_qfn\": $!\n");

   push @out_fhs, $out_fh;
}

my $in_qfn = '...';
open(my $in_fh, '<', $in_qfn)
   or die("Can't create \"$in_qfn\": $!\n");

my $i = 0;
while (<$in_fh>) {
   print { $out_fhs[ $i++ % @fhs ] } $_;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, its a bit hard understand your code..  could you clarify a bit?

Comment: I believe you want lines 1, n+1, 2n+1, ... in one file; lines 2, n+2, 2n+2, ... in another; etc